# In Python 3 when I send a .csv file as an attachment it is missing lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that queries some systems and then appends the results to a CSV file. This script runs once a week and then emails the CSV file as the last step. However when I open the attachment I get the information on the previous run but not the information from the current run.I can go to the machine running the script and see that the file actually has the current information.

Here are snippets:
File Open:

```
out_exists = os.path.isfile('/depot/sgcap/grid_capacities.csv')
if out_exists:
        out = open("/depot/sgcap/grid_capacities.csv","a")
else:
        out = open("/depot/sgcap/grid_capacities.csv","a")
        out.write(('Date,Site,Installed Capacity (TB),Used Capacity (TB)'))
```

File write and close:

```
                        out.write('\n'+ str(date) + "," + str(s) + ',' + str(xisc_tb) + ',' + str(xusc_tb))


        else:
                print('\n Errored on http request with status ', response.status_code)
out.close
```

And lastly the email portion (shamelessly stolen):

```
#bundle it up and send the email
email = 'root@a.machine.com'
password = ''
send_to_email = ['some.guy@wherever.com','another.guy@wherever.com']
subject = 'StorageGRID Capacities'
message = 'This morning\'s capacity report'
file_location = ('/depot/sgcap/grid_capacities.csv')

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email
msg['To'] =  ", ".join(send_to_email)
msg['Subject'] = subject

msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

# Setup the attachment
filename = os.path.basename(file_location)
attachment = open(file_location, "rb")
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload(attachment.read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

# Attach the attachment to the MIMEMultipart object
msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('my.mailserver.com', 25)
#server.starttls()
#server.login(email, password)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Not sure if that is only a copy paste error, but `out.close` is missing the brackets `out.close` that could end up in not correctly closing the file and hence not having the correct data, I would always suggest `with open(filename, 'a') as file: ...`

Comment: Appart from that it is hard to tell where the error comes from because the code is lacking many parts -> the problem could be in the missing part of the code

Comment: @TanjaBayer The missing brackets did the trick. Please put that in as an answer so I can mark it so.

Comment: The answer from Chris is already explaining it quite nice putting the same answer there dose not make sense, just mark his as the Accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your writes must be flushed to disk before you send the file. Before that, they are buffered and have NOT been written to the file on disk.

Best practice for flushing is simply to ensure the file handle is closed, as Tanja Bayer notes, either using `out.close()` or better practice, using a context manager via `open ... as`.

There are less common cases where you might want to call `out.flush()` directly but those are a different use case, for long-running processes that need to keep files open for a long time.

Short answer: for normal / small file writes, just close the file handle to write data to disk.